# Address of stack memory returned when overloading operator [ ]

Tags: c++, char, operator-overloading

I'm encountering some issues with overloading the [] operator for a problem in class. This is the function for the overloading:

```
const char* Person::operator[](const char* str)
{
    if (strcmp(str, "name") == 0)
        return reinterpret_cast<const char *>atoi(name);

    if (strcmp(str, "age") == 0)
    {
        char temp[4];
        _itoa(age, temp, 10);
        //cout << temp;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

The class defition looks like this

```
class Person
{
private:
    const char* name;
    unsigned int age;
    double height;
    int gradeNo;
    int grades[10];
public:
    Person();
    Person(const char* name, int age, double height);
    void addGrade(int grade);
    const char* operator [] (const char* str);
    operator int();
};
```

The problem I'm getting is with the `return temp;` line from the operator overload function. CLion returns the following warning: `Address of stack memory associated with local variable 'temp' returned`

Sure enough, when trying to use the operator, the value returned is a memory address. How can I go about fixing this? Is it related to the return type of the function?

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of C-style strings.  A lot of problems will then go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking an address to a temporary (that is located on the stack), that will leave the returned pointer dangling almost immediately.

I would very strongly suggest using `std::string` for strings, do not write C++ just as C with classes.

Then return by `std::string` by value here. Bad C-like alternative is to allocate the string on the heap and return that, preferably as `std::unique_ptr` at least.

#### EDIT after the comment below:

Since you are required to convert an integer to string and return the value, you cannot return a temporary variable, the result must outlive the method. There are basically two bad options:

1. Make `temp` static, this way the pointer remains valid. Downside is the function is no longer re-entrant. This is safer because it won't leak.

```
const char* foo(int age){
    static char temp[4];
    _itoa(age, temp, 10);
    return temp;
}
```

2. Return a heap allocated string. Big danger is that you are leaving the user to deallocate it:

```
const char* foo(int age){
    char* temp = new char[256];
    _itoa(age, temp, 10);
    return temp;
}
```

I believe you also have a typo in your code:

```
return reinterpret_cast<const char *>atoi(name);
```

The `atoi` should not be there, right?`reinterpret_cast` should not be needed.

Comment: I know this would be the best way to go about this, but we haven't gotten to the part regarding the std library, so I'm indirectly forced to use normal chars

Comment: Ugh, so another teacher bend on teaching 20-year old C-like C++ first to proof to you how hard the language is... Please show them [Stop teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk). I will edit my answer with a bad solution.

Comment: @RaduDeleanu `char name[20]` will alocate 20 bytes for the name. `char*name;` will not allocate anything and you must create a dynamic array as is done in case `1.`  . So, prefer `char name[MAX_LEN];`. Feel free to ask more questions :)

Comment: No problem :). But there should be `delete[] ptr;` on the returned pointer somewhere later in the code. Otherwise you have a memory leak - see how bad the C-like solution is.